# Castor compilation of schema produces different class hierarchy depending on elements in schema

Tags: java, castor

While maintaining a castor based system, I amend the source schema to produce a new set of classes and find that introducing a new element produces a different class hierarchy. This is true of any element type.

Briefly, the current schema creates class `foo` which extends `fooParent` which extends `fooGrandparent`.  Introduce a new element in the schema, which is unrelated to these classes,  and Castor now produces `foo` AND `fooParent` which both extend `fooGrandparent`.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: More information is needed before someone can help.

Comment: Yes, please provide the relevant parts of the XSD